# "for" loop is not executing on the remote server using SSH

Tags: shell-script, shell, scripting, ksh, aix

The below "for" loop works locally on the same server.

But when triggered through "ssh" protocol on remote servers, the output is not received.

Please, can anyone suggest how to make it work while to be triggered on remote servers.

```
for i in $(cat Server_List)  # Works
do   # Works
echo $i  # Works
ssh $i '$(for a in `/usr/sbin/lspath|grep scsi|awk '{print \$2}'|sort|uniq`;   # Doesn't Work
do    # Doesn't Work
echo "\$a `/usr/sbin/lspath |awk '/'\$a' /' |uniq|awk '/Enabled/'|wc -l`;done)'   # Doesn't Work
done  # Works
```

Comment: You have single quotes both in the command you're sending to the remote server and inside the command itself. You'll need to escape the quotes inside the commands you have on the ssh command line.

Comment: Are you really intending to execute the _output_ of your for loop as a command?

Comment: @doneal24 - can you pls. write exactly where I would need to escape the quotes as I am just new to these coding area.. thanks..

Comment: @roaima - yes as a command through the coding support..

Comment: Try to verify your script into https://shellcheck.net to see why it doesn't work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `heredoc` to run a multiline commands via ssh:

```
ssh user@host <<'EOC' 
  for a in $(/usr/sbin/lspath | awk '/scsi/ {print $2}'| sort -u); do
    # do something
  done
EOC
```